# Starting service in android to read message after fixed interval

Tags: java, android, eclipse, service, android-asynctask

I am able to read message of user when the application gets installed. But what I want is that even after the application is closed, I should be able to read user message after a fixed interval of time. For example, application like Walnut that reads specific message and gives alerts automatically if any new message has come. How can I do the same.

Comment: use notification with alarm manager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Alarm manager and Pending Intent

Initiate Alarm manager here.

```
AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) this
                    .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                    new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver_update.class),
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                    0, yourTimeInterval, pendingIntent);
```

And in AlarmReceiver_update class:

```
public class AlarmReceiver_update extends BroadcastReceiver
{
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
// Do whatever you want
}
}
```

And in Your AndroidManifest file register your receiver:

```
<receiver android:name="com.x.y.AlarmReceiver_update" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.test.BROADCAST" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

This is not complete just sample you have any doubt just comment.

Comment: Its not necessary to use AsyncTask?

Comment: Sorry i don't understand what you mean ?

Comment: When I googled this problem, at most places its mentioned that AsyncTask class should be used, so I wanted to ask that which method is more efficient

Comment: You can use asynkTask. This sample code is just used to initiate task. IN my answer AlarmReceiver_update class have onReceive method. Just call Asynktask from here. So i mention do whatever you want

Comment: I think this method is better than Asynktask

Comment: Ok Thanks, will definitely try this and will ask if any problem comes.

Answer (score 0):

You shuold use an alarm manager to set a repeating alarm.

Then you should setup a `BroadcastReceiver` Service that read the user messages onRecieve.

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // Run the task to read the user messages

    }
}
```

This is a good [tutorial](http://javatechig.com/android/repeat-alarm-example-in-android#3-defining-alarm-broadcastreceiver)

Have a look at the below links to learn how to notify the user if you found new message.

1. http://javatechig.com/android/repeat-alarm-example-in-android#3-defining-alarm-broadcastreceiver
2. http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html